# GA4 ecommerce (gtag.js): Send Universal Analytics events - Will Option 1 Still work on 7/1: enable connected site tags

Tags: google-analytics, ads

Will the UA tag continue to pass data to GA4 properties after UA is deprecated on 7/1?

[Option 1: Use the GA4 Setup Assistant and enable connected site tags](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/ecommerce/gtagjs-ua-to-ga4#option_1_use_the_ga4_setup_assistant_and_enable_connected_site_tags)

We've created new GA4 accounts (thousand+) for our customers and enabled the connected site tag settings so that we can re-use the existing website UA tag. The UA tag is currently passing data to the GA4 properties as expected. Since we have so many sites we would rather not have to add the new GA4 tag and make changes to the GA4 property settings - if we don't have to. [We would rather not do Option 2 to 1000+ sites](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/ecommerce/gtagjs-ua-to-ga4#option_2_update_your_gtagjs_snippet)

This question applies to the new GA4 and their associated Google Ads accounts data also.